# In reality, are server controls rarely added programmatically to aspx pages?

Tags: asp.net

I mean, it's easy to add a Button programmactically to an aspx page, but a server control's event handler probably has to be set early in the page life cycle (maybe before Control.Load event). As a result in reality, are dynamic controls rarely added to apsx pages?

I wish there is a way to call postback at the server, so that a event is never too late.

Comment: Please rephrase the question so it doesn't seem like you are looking for how much people like or dislike dynamic controls. Please clarify " wish there is a way to call postback at the server, so that a event is never too late." An actual problem you are facing would help clarify what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the controls in the PreInit or Init events, there are no problems.  I dynamically add controls to my webforms pages all the time.

Comment: When you dynamically add controls too early in the life cycle, it has no chance to receive any input from sources like events or viewstate, you may as well add it declaratively. How do you add dynamic controls based on certain events? For example, how many numeric page buttons to add to a page based on the number of database records?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do would be read [Truly Understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) and [Truly Understanding Dynamic Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx) -- you really can't start to do anything really hinky in webforms without that knowledge.